# Exe not starting in windows ce 5.0 emulator

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm developing mobile application for device running windowce CE. I'm trying to get my app started on windows CE emulator. On the emulator i have installed net compact framework 3.5 and compact sql. My app also installes from cab succesfully but when i try to run my app nothing happens. No error message or anything.

I have tried not deploying my app from cab but just copying files over to emulator but no use. In device it is working but i'm not always able to use the device when i need to run my app for testing.

Maybe someone has idea what to look or try.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run it on the debugger?
It may be that the app is accessing some API or some driver that is not supported by the emulator and this prevents it from starting.
Starting in the debuger you may be able to step trough the main rountine or, at least, will have a chance to see some debug messages.

Comment: For some reason i can't connect CE emulator to Visual Studio 2008. If followed this [link](http://www.gllonardi.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=48:connecting-the-ce-50-emulator-to-vs2005&catid=34:visual-studio-2005&Itemid=61) but i can't ping ip assigned in my emulator.

Found that there are others with similar problem [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1ca759f5-9dad-4174-830c-0af25b5d9ceb/unable-to-launch-our-application-on-win-ce-50-emulator-which-has-cf-20-installed?forum=microsoftdeviceemu) but no solution there either.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Windows CE emulator running the same processor type than the real device? In contrast to Windows Mobile 6.x, Windows CE can also run on x86 instead of ArmV4i (XScale).
Did you really install the correct CF runtimes?

If you are running the stand alone device emulator there is an option to dock the emulated device and then use simply ActiveSync or WMDC. TCP/IP (viw emulated network) with emulator will no more work on Windows 7 PCs, the driver cannot be installed.

If the above does not help watch the Visual Studio Build window when you deploy a debug version of your app. VS will then deploy all necessary CAB and DLLs to the device.